# What exactly is the initializationSteps parameter in Kmeans++ in Spark MLLib?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I know what k-means is and I also understand what k-means++ algorithm is. I believe the only change is the way the initial K centers are found.

In the ++ version we initially choose a center and using a probability distribution we choose the remaining k-1 centers.

In the MLLib algorithm for k-means what is the `initializationSteps` parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be precise k-means++ is an algorithm for choosing initial centers and it doesn't describe a whole training process.

MLLib k-means is using [k-means||](http://theory.stanford.edu/~sergei/papers/vldb12-kmpar.pdf) for initialization which is a distributed variant of ++. It samples not one, but multiple points for number of iterations.

`initializationSteps` corresponds to the number of iterations and according to [the original paper](http://theory.stanford.edu/~sergei/papers/vldb12-kmpar.pdf) should be roughly O(log n).