# Why is Spark Mllib KMeans algorithm extremely slow?

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-analysis, data-mining, k-means, apache-spark-mllib

I'm having the same problem as in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34616842/kmeans-for-sentiment-analysis-on-spark), but I don't have enough points to add a comment there. My dataset has 1 Million rows, 100 cols. I'm using Mllib KMeans also and it is extremely slow. The job never finishes in fact and I have to kill it. I am running this on Google cloud (dataproc). It runs if I ask for a smaller number of clusters (k=1000), but still take more than 35 minutes. I need it to run for k~5000. I have no idea why is it so slow. The data is properly partitioned given the number of workers/nodes and SVD on a 1 million x ~300,000 col matrix takes ~3 minutes, but when it comes to KMeans it just goes into a black hole. I am now trying a lower number of iterations (2 instead of 100), but I feel something is wrong somewhere.

```
KMeansModel Cs = KMeans.train(datamatrix, k, 100);//100 iteration, changed to 2 now. # of clusters k=1000 or 5000
```

Comment: changing the # iteration to 2 made NO difference at all.

Comment: Kai, I have a [similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39260820/is-sparks-kmeans-unable-to-handle-bigdata). However, in my case the job simply *hangs*, it's not just that it's slow. Would you see any progress when running your job and it would be just slow, or it would do nothing, like in my case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the reason is relatively simple. You use quite large k and combine it with an expensive initialization algorithm.

By default Spark is using as distributed variant of [K-means++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means%2B%2B) called K-means|| (see [What exactly is the initializationSteps parameter in Kmeans++ in Spark MLLib?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34345638/1560062)). Distributed version is roughly *O(k)* so with larger k you can expect slower start. This should explain why you see no improvement when you reduce number of iterations.

Using large K is also expensive when model is trained. Spark is using a variant of Lloyds which is roughly *O(nkdi)*.

If you expect complex structure of the data there most likely a better algorithms out there to handle this than K-Means but if you really want to stick with it you start with using random initialization.

Comment: are you saying that most of the time is consumed by this "initialization"?

Comment: I am saying this an expensive step and for accounts for behavior you see. But more important is that training K-means with thousands of clusters cannot perform well.

Comment: just ran spark job with 5000 custer, random initialization, finished in 7 min!! Awesome!! now I'll go read the papers see the impact on accuracy. Thank you, yet again zero. As for the number of clusters, I think the dimensionality of the problem is a lot more critical-> in very high dims every point is "far" from every other point. The number of points isn't really important for more than execution speed.

Comment: Dimensionality can affect the output but for different reasons (both algorithmically and available optimizations) doesn't affect running time as much. But I am glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Please try other implementations of k-means. Some like the variants in [ELKI](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/) are *way* better than Spark, even on only a single CPU. You will be surprised how much performance you can get out of a single node, without going to a cluster! From my experiments, you would need at least a 100 node cluster to beat good local implementations, unfortunately.

I read that [these C++ versions](https://github.com/BaylorCS/baylorml) are multi-core (but single-node) and probably the fastest K-means you can find right now, but I have not yet tried that myself yet (for all my needs, the ELKI versions were bazingly fast, finishing in a few seconds on my largest data sets).