# How to train a ML model in sparklyr and predict new values on another dataframe?

Tags: r, apache-spark, apache-spark-ml, sparklyr

Consider the following example

```
dtrain <- data_frame(text = c("Chinese Beijing Chinese",
                              "Chinese Chinese Shanghai",
                              "Chinese Macao",
                              "Tokyo Japan Chinese"),
                     doc_id = 1:4,
                     class = c(1, 1, 1, 0))

dtrain_spark <- copy_to(sc, dtrain, overwrite = TRUE)

> dtrain_spark
# Source:   table<dtrain> [?? x 3]
# Database: spark_connection
  text                     doc_id class
  <chr>                     <int> <dbl>
1 Chinese Beijing Chinese       1     1
2 Chinese Chinese Shanghai      2     1
3 Chinese Macao                 3     1
4 Tokyo Japan Chinese           4     0
```

Here I have the classic Naive Bayes example where `class` identifies documents falling into the `China` category.

I am able to run a Naives Bayes classifier in `sparklyr` by doing the following:

```
dtrain_spark %>% 
ft_tokenizer(input.col = "text", output.col = "tokens") %>% 
ft_count_vectorizer(input_col = 'tokens', output_col = 'myvocab') %>% 
  select(myvocab, class) %>%  
  ml_naive_bayes( label_col = "class", 
                  features_col = "myvocab", 
                  prediction_col = "pcol",
                  probability_col = "prcol", 
                  raw_prediction_col = "rpcol",
                  model_type = "multinomial", 
                  smoothing = 0.6, 
                  thresholds = c(0.2, 0.4))
```

which outputs:

```
NaiveBayesModel (Transformer)
<naive_bayes_5e946aec597e> 
 (Parameters -- Column Names)
  features_col: myvocab
  label_col: class
  prediction_col: pcol
  probability_col: prcol
  raw_prediction_col: rpcol
 (Transformer Info)
  num_classes:  int 2 
  num_features:  int 6 
  pi:  num [1:2] -1.179 -0.368 
  theta:  num [1:2, 1:6] -1.417 -0.728 -2.398 -1.981 -2.398 ... 
  thresholds:  num [1:2] 0.2 0.4
```

However, I have two major questions:

1. How can I assess the performance of this classifier in-sample? Where are the accuracy metrics?
2. Even more importantly, how can I use this trained model to predict new values, say, in the following `spark` test dataframe?

Test data:

```
dtest <- data_frame(text = c("Chinese Chinese Chinese Tokyo Japan",
                             "random stuff"))

dtest_spark <- copy_to(sc, dtest, overwrite = TRUE)

> dtest_spark
# Source:   table<dtest> [?? x 1]
# Database: spark_connection
  text                               
  <chr>                              
1 Chinese Chinese Chinese Tokyo Japan
2 random stuff
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How can I assess the performance of this classifier in-sample? Where are the accuracy metrics?

In general (there are some models  which provide some form of summary), evaluation on training dataset is a separate step in Apache Spark. This fits nicely in the native `Pipeline` API.

**Background**:

Spark ML Pipelines are primarily build from two types of objects:

- `Transformers` - objects which provide `transform` method, which map `DataFrame` to updated `DataFrame`.

  You can `transform` using `Transformer` with `ml_transform` method.
- `Estimators` - objects which provide `fit` method, which map `DataFrame` to `Transfomer`. By convention corresponding `Estimator` / `Transformer` pairs are called `Foo` / `FooModel`.

  You can `fit` `Estimator` in `sparklyr` using `ml_fit` model.

Additionally ML Pipelines can be combined with `Evaluators` (see `ml_*_evaluator` and `ml_*_eval` methods) which can be used to compute different metrics on the transformed data, based on columns generated by a model (usually probability column or raw prediction).

You can apply `Evaluator` using `ml_evaluate` method.

Are related components include cross validator and train validation splits, which can be used for parameter tuning.

**Examples**:

`sparklyr` `PipelineStages` can be evaluated eagerly (as in your own code), by passing data directly, or lazily by passing a `spark_connection` instance and calling aforementioned methods (`ml_fit`, `ml_transform`, etc.).

It means you can define a `Pipeline` as follows:

```
pipeline <- ml_pipeline(
  ft_tokenizer(sc, input.col = "text", output.col = "tokens"),
  ft_count_vectorizer(sc, input_col = 'tokens', output_col = 'myvocab'),
  ml_naive_bayes(sc, label_col = "class", 
              features_col = "myvocab", 
              prediction_col = "pcol",
              probability_col = "prcol", 
              raw_prediction_col = "rpcol",
              model_type = "multinomial", 
              smoothing = 0.6, 
              thresholds = c(0.2, 0.4),
              uid = "nb")
)
```

Fit the `PipelineModel`:

```
model <- ml_fit(pipeline, dtrain_spark)
```

Transform, and apply one of available `Evaluators`:

```
ml_transform(model, dtrain_spark) %>% 
  ml_binary_classification_evaluator(
    label_col="class", raw_prediction_col= "rpcol", 
    metric_name = "areaUnderROC")
```

```
[1] 1
```

or

```
evaluator <- ml_multiclass_classification_evaluator(
    sc,
    label_col="class", prediction_col= "pcol", 
    metric_name = "f1")

ml_evaluate(evaluator, ml_transform(model, dtrain_spark))
```

```
[1] 1
```

> Even more importantly, how can I use this trained model to predict new values, say, in the following spark test dataframe?

Use either `ml_transform` or `ml_predict` (the latter one is a convince wrapper, which applies further transformations on the output):

```
ml_transform(model, dtest_spark)
```

```
# Source:   table<sparklyr_tmp_cc651477ec7> [?? x 6]
# Database: spark_connection
  text                                tokens     myvocab   rpcol   prcol   pcol
  <chr>                               <list>     <list>    <list>  <list> <dbl>
1 Chinese Chinese Chinese Tokyo Japan <list [5]> <dbl [6]> <dbl [… <dbl …     0
2 random stuff                        <list [2]> <dbl [6]> <dbl [… <dbl …     1
```

**Cross validation**:

*There is not enough data in the example*, but you cross validate and fit hyperparameters as shown below:

```
# dontrun
ml_cross_validator(
  dtrain_spark,
  pipeline, 
  list(nb=list(smoothing=list(0.8, 1.0))),  # Note that name matches UID
  evaluator=evaluator)
```

**Notes**:

- Please keep in mind that, Spark's multinomial Naive Bayes implementation [considers only binary feature (0 or not 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45634540).
- If you use `Pipelines` with `Vector` columns (not `formula`-based calls), I strongly recommend using standardized (default) column names:

  - `label` for dependent variable.
  - `features` for assembled independent variables.
  - `rawPrediction`, `prediction`, `probability` for raw prediction, prediction and probability columns respectively.

Comment: no worries. thanks for the precision! do you have some ideas about the parameter tuning thing that you were mentioning? thanks!

Comment: really amazing answer! well deserved bounty my friend :)

Comment: Thanks @kevinykuo ℕʘʘḆḽḘ

Comment: @user6910411 can I ask just a follow up question? something that does not work very well in the current code is when I need to use some `mutate()` clause between `ft_tokenizer()` and `ft_count_vectorizer()` in the `pipeline` above. What is the right syntax then? I tried to use the `ft_dplyr_transformer()` but somehow I must be missing something here. Thanks!

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ Do you have anything specific in mind? Does it work on the output of `ft_tokenizer`? And what specifically does not work well? Spark complex types are not exactly R friendly...

Comment: @user6910411 I simply have a `mutate(myflag = text %rlike% 'user69)` between the two. Simple `dplyr` verbs essentially. Thanks again!

Comment: I mean here in the example that could be just something like `mutate(myflag = text %rlike% 'China)`

Comment: Huh, I actually don't see how you can integrate these two. Maybe @kevinykuo does? But SQL transformer will work just fine `ft_sql_transformer(sc, "SELECT *, text RLIKE 'China' AS myflag FROM __THIS__")`

Comment: You can do something like `my_sql_transformer <- ft_dplyr_transformer(sc, dtrain_spark %>% mutate(myflag = text %rlike% 'China'))` which generates a `SQLTransformer` for you, and you can put `my_sql_transformer` as a stage in your pipeline. You'd have to put it as the first stage though, since dplyr is explicit about column selection (i.e. it doesn't generate `SELECT *`). Feel free to open an issue on the repo if you feel like this behavior blocks a lot of use cases. You can also explicitly define the SQL transformer as @user6910411 suggests.